# "CASE" statement within "WHERE" clause in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, t-sql, case-when

i have a select statement like this

```
select x, y , z from table a
where CAST( CAST(DATEColumn AS VARCHAR) AS DATE) between  
    case when a.columnx = '1900-01-01' then CAST( CAST(DATEColumn AS VARCHAR) AS DATE) else c.columnx end
    and cast( c.CustomerShipToRecTrmDt as date)
```

why does this case statement does not work
whereas the case statement works if i hardcode the dates?

Comment: Show both examples please. And some raw data. Actully why don't you create a simple http://sqlfiddle.com/ so that people can see the data and the query

Comment: That query is invalid.  No END and what is up with the extra CAST?  Please fix your post for more help.  And you should have an ELSE in the case.

Answer (score 0):

What are you casting a date columns to `varchar` and then back to a `date`?  I think this does what you want:

```
select x, y , z 
rom table a
where DATEColumn  between  
          (case when a.columnx = '1900-01-01' then DATEColumn else cast(c.columnx as date) end and
          cast( c.CustomerShipToRecTrmDt as date)
```

You can eliminate the `case` statement from the `where` clause by doing:

```
where DATEColumn >= cast(c.columnx as date) and DateColumns <= cast( c.CustomerShipToRecTrmDt as date)
```

The comparison to `1900-01-01` doesn't affect the `>=` part, unless you are working with dates before 1900 (I'm guessing this is unlikely).

Also, whenever casting values to `varchar()`, always include the length (as in `varchar(255)`).

Comment: select x, y , z from table a
where CAST( CAST(DATEColumn AS VARCHAR) AS DATE) between  
    case when a.columnx = '1900-01-01' then CAST( CAST(DATEColumn AS VARCHAR) AS DATE) else c.columnx end
    and cast( c.CustomerShipToRecTrmDt as date)

I have columnx....if columnx in that particular column is 1900-01-01, then i am saying...give it DateColumn (which is int, but i am converting that to Date), else columnx